# How to ignore invalid TLS

Tags: go, prometheus, amazon-cloudwatch, tls1.2

I fetch prometheus metrics by sending HTTP Get() to prometheus endpoint. If the prometheus endpoint is `http` this works, but throws a error when it is `https`.

Now I want to have a user setting as `ignore_invalid_tls`, which can be set to true or false.

To implement this, I need to ignore the error caused by the `https` endpoint.

I tried this approach:

```
client := http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Duration(configuration.Endpoint.Timeout) * time.Second,
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    },
}
```

but this only ignores the bad certificates.

The error I get when the prometheus endpoint is https is:

> http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Comment: Error IMHO means that you're hitting https:// endpoint (so your golang client expects HTTPS traffic) but server serves HTTP on HTTPS port...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot generically ignore "invalid TLS". The TLS handshake includes the **local** validation of the certificate, which can be disabled with `InsecureSkipVerify`. But if the other side simply does not speak TLS in the first place like in *"server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"* then this cannot be ignored. This is like the client speaking English while the server speaks Spanish - one cannot simply ignore that both cannot understand each other and continue with the communication.